# Kohana accessing client ip

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I am using `kohana 3.2`, and i would like to acces client ip from request class, in [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#property%3aclient_ip) i can see `public static string $client_ip` which should contain client ip, now if i try to access it i like so:

```
Request::$client_ip;
```

I get: `string(3) "::1"` it makes no sense at all, what am i doing wrong, or maybe it's impossible to access it?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? You access your script locally, your IPv6 address is `::1`

Comment: @Thorsten oh my god how could i forget about that...

Comment: How to get client ip address in kohana 2.3.4? can any one tell me the code?

Comment: @jeeva I'm not sure about 2.3.4 but you can always just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: @Linas Thank you, i got the solution. In Kohana 2.3.4 we use $this->input->ip_address();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You access your script locally, your IPv6 address is `::1`

Comment: +1 for the ipv6. Good to bring this up as most new dev's wont know wtf  ::1 is.